# Read specific columns using python

Tags: python

I have a file like this

```
SEQ_NUM|ICS_ORIG_STRT_DT|EDW_FIRST_OUT_IFP_DT|CURR_DT|DEV_GE_NUM_DAYS|DEV_LE_NUM_DAYS|FILENAME|CAMPAIGN_NAME_DESC| CAMPAIGN_WAVE|MARKET_SEGMENT|CAMPAIGN_NAME|CAMPAIGN_WAVE_RUN|EFFORT_TYPE|EFFORT_NUM|UU_ID|PRINT_ACCT_NUM|PRINT_PUB_CD|PREFIX|SUFFIX|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|EMAIL|PHONE_NUM|BUS_PHONE|CO_NAME|STREET_NUM|ADDR|ADDR2|CITY|STATE_PROVINCE|ZIP_POSTAL|ZIP4|TRACK_CD|VANITY_URL|BILL_FORM|LETTER_TEXT|OUTER
130|20140401|00010101|20140728|85||Apr14WSJ_CNYR_NOEMAIL_CAP_TM_20140728.txt|Apr14WSJ_CNYR_NOEMAIL_CAP_TM|WSJ_CNYR_NOEMAIL_CAP_TM|CNYR|WSJ_CNYR_NOEMAIL_CAP|Apr14|TM|||032714296269|J|||ARTHUR|MURPHY||9784255147|||46|LANTERN###WAY||SHIRLEY|MA|01464|2136|aaqecw0c||||
```

I am trying to get `PRINT_PUB_CODE =130,PRINT_ACCT_NUM= 20140401 CO_NAME = 00010101` and `prefix = 20140728` and so on.
I am new to python and tried this code along with other codes but the the results coming like

```
130   
20140401
None
aaqecw0c
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.What I can do to fix this.
The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
csv.register_dialect('piper', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
with open('temp1.txt','rb') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='piper'):
        print row['PRINT_PUB_CODE']
        print row['PRINT_ACCT_NUM']
        print row['CO_NAME']
        print row['PREFIX']
```

original file is at http://pastebin.com/QFvLwcHu

Comment: Have you noticed that you have two `PREFIX` columns in your header? That seems like it would cause some problems.

Comment: @Kevin good catch - that'd definitely cause problems with `DictReader` :)

Comment: the header was bad now fixed it.ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` is writing out exactly what you tell it to, namely the values themselves. If you want name/value pairs, you'll need to arrange to format it yourself.

Try this in place of the existing print statements:

```
names = ('PRINT_PUB_CODE', 'PRINT_ACCT_NUM', 'CO_NAME', 'PREFIX')
print(", ".join("%s=%r" % (n, row[n]) for n in names))
```

---

Here's how the above code works:

- `", ".join(sequence)` takes a sequence of strings and concatenates them together with `", "` between each value.
- `%` is the [string formatting operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), which takes the string on the left and replaces patterns like `%s` and `%r` with formatted values from the tuple on the right
- `%s` is the format code for a string, and it's used for the name in front of the `=` sign.
- `%r` is the format code for "string representation of," or [repr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr), and it's used to convert the value in the `row` to a string.
- `for n in names` is part of a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps), making Python evaluate the `%` operator once for each element in the `names` tuple.

Comment: Ty Dan.it Worked can you tell me why it is fetching only one row.

Comment: The input file you pasted in the question only has one row.

Comment: The original file has lot of files.

Comment: Dan,I would also like to know if I can apply if condition here.I want to check for every value of 'EFFORT_TYPE'== TM RETURN SOME CONCATENATION OF of some rows .

Comment: Try an editor without word wrap; the records in the original file are separated by spaces, not newlines. You can fix the file in a unix-like environment with `tr ' ' '\n'`, or you can change the first parameter of `DictReader` to `csvfile.read().split(' ')`.

Comment: To filter the output, just wrap the `print` statement in an `if` block.

Comment: I did this abc = str( print row['EFFORT_TYPE'] )
if str = 'TM':
   return 1
else:
   return 0  But it isnt running.

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors there. Probably out-of-scope for SO comments. Consider reading up some more on python syntax for [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in), [`if` statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) and [special behavior of `print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print)

Comment: abc = str((print row['EFFORT_TYPE']))
if abc == 'TM':
   print ("sadas")
else:
   print ("adass")

Comment: Still not getting it.Please help.